# Server 2012 R2 / Windows 8.1 Start Menu Search as run

Tags: search, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012-r2

No clue if this has been asked before, but will try anyway.
I just installed Server 2012R2 on my pc (Similar to Windows 8.1) - 
I'm starting to get the hang of it, however there is one thing bothering me, but i cannot find where to change it.

Before in Win7(/2008R2) i used to type my (run)commands in the search bar and execute them right away.. however with 8.1 that doesn't seem to work. I have been looking for a setting like that but haven't been able to find it.

Example:

[image]

when I type "shutdown -s -t 1" in the search and hit enter it actually searched on it. Back in Windows 7 it would have executed it.

Does someone know the setting I'm looking for?